Interacting Instrumental Variables Using fixest Package
In the following example, I regress y on and x1 and x2 and instrument for x1 using z1. I'd like to add another term, the interaction between x1 and x2, but I'm unsure how. Can someone point me in the right direction?
library(fixest)

# Example data
data <- data.frame(
  y = rnorm(100),
  x1 = rnorm(100),
  x2 = rnorm(100),
  z1 = rnorm(100)
)

# IV regression
iv_model <- feols(y ~ x2 | x1 ~ z1, data = data)

# Display the results
summary(iv_model)

I've tried adding the interaction between x1 and x2 to the following command, however, fixest returns the following error
Error in feols(y ~ x2 + x2 * x1 | x1 ~ z1, data = data) : 
  Endogenous variables should not be used as exogenous regressors. The variable 'x1' was found in the first part of the multipart formula: it should not be there.

I also added the interaction term to the right RHS of the | but received the same error message concerning x2.  The following code runs, however, I'm not sure if it's correct. Could someone please confirm?
iv_model <- feols(y ~ x2 | x1 + I(x1*x2) ~ z1 + I(z1*x2), data = data)

